# GA API - Acquisition reports by channels

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I use google analytics api v3 and I have two questions:

1Q: Is possible get AcquisitionChannel data grouped by Default channel (Primary dimens.)?

2Q: Why is column "visits" different in Default channel Email and source Email?

thanks

Comment: Can you add additional details to your question? In Que 2 are you suggesting a discrepancy between your metrics?